# remove default sink

Tags: linux, pulseaudio

I am trying to set sink as default :

```
$pacmd set-default-sink sinkName
```

so my question is... is there a way to unset the sink as default in case I am to unload it (remove)? I mean should I unset the default sink manually before removing it?

Thanks

Comment: No, there is always a default sink, at least dummy output.

Comment: @IporSircer Thanks. No, I mean if I remove default sink manually will PulseAudio set some sink as default one automatically or I should do so manually?

Answer (score 1):

Pacmd command to set default sink is written to home folder

```
cat ~/.config/pulse/*default-sink
```

will confirm 'sinkName'

If you delete  file, Pulseaudio will rebuild it again when next restarted, but may not set default you want

For example, If you have 2 playback devices - Analog stereo and HDMI:

- set HDMI as Default device and audio playback stream will try to connect there first
- If HDMI is not connected, Analog stereo used as fallback device
- do not have to set to set fallback device unless more than 2 devices